# VirtualBox licensing

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I want to create a virtual Windows 10 machine, hosted on Mac OS. The virtual machine will be used only by me for software development. However, the MacBook is property of my employers and I will develop software for their company. Do we need to purchase a VirtualBox license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. VirtualBox is [licensed](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ) under the terms of the [GNU General Public License version 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License). You do need to accept those licensing terms, but do not need to **pay** money for the software.

Note that the VirtualBox Extension Pack is distributed under different licensing terms. You are using VirtualBox in a commercial environment. If you are also using the VirtualBox Extension Pack, you'll need to [purchase a license](https://shop.oracle.com/apex/f?p=dstore:product:25714122115624::NO:RP,6:P6_LPI,P6_PPI:114347640102492137513432) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I can tell you that without reading the License Agreement.  This is because I'm a software developer, contractor, and freelancer.  You do not want anything on their equipment that is licensed to you.  EVER.

This is for legal reasons.  Let's say you load up software licensed to you on the machine and then your employment with them ends.   The new guy receives the machine with little changed, and discovers the software install.  Most people who have a business degree know nothing about software licensing until it bites them, so his boss tells him "sure, go ahead, pick up where the last guy left off".  That guy does a horrible job or worse, maliciously damages the company. Using your software license.
Be it litigation or criminal charges, the company has to lawyer up. It has committed software piracy on accident, and they'll claim it was your responsibility to remove the software before turning in the hardware.  Guess who else now has to hire a lawyer?

Similarly, it's a headache for the boss and the next guy.   Not just for the above reasons, but in transition.   Let's say a year after Joe Shmoe quit, license for a software package that is free for personal use (but not for corporate use) expires and requires his login to re-up.  Nobody knows it.  Even if they did, a smart programmer wouldn't do it, and would go to the boss, who now realizes they have a $*n* purchase that wasn't in the budget that has to be made.  It takes a month to wrench out and slows development drastically.

Finally, say you thought it all through, removed the software when you left, and carried the license to the next machine you use.  The company you worked for gets called out for the possible license violation by a whistleblower (usually someone who works for the company but feels slighted by it or is fired). The software company then investigates and finds that they have no record of a license in the name of your former employer, but that you worked for them.  While this isn't uncommon for contractors and would be seen as normal, it's a dangerous issue for employees, and can still look bad if you're a contractor using their equipment.  There's a good chance you'll see at least a summons to court, or a termination of your license and blacklisting from licensing from the company again.

Edit: There are fuzzier exceptions.  For instance, Adobe Suite may be licensed "to you" but it's not.  You just have a login, and your company is purchasing the license, and there's a paper trail to prove it.  Adobe makes it a PITA for license purchases for only one developer just to prevent the above scenarios, and usually will just terminate an account and sell the company a new license instead of "transferring" an account.   The point is, the paper trail goes back to the company, not to you, and that's what is important.

TL;DR: If it's going on company hardware, it better be company software.

Comment: I get your point, however VirtualBox can be used for free without creating any licenses and accounts. So my question is regarding VirtualBox specifically. I still agree with everything you said though.

Comment: You still don't want to be the person installing and using it and risking violating the license.  Oracle owns VirtualBox and their terms are [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ).  If I were going to risk any of the above, Oracle is not the company with which I'd risk it. They hire IP lawyers by the building.  I wouldn't install it and use it until you have the OK from your company's attorney at the very least.